# Continuous function on $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ that is not Lipschitz Continuous?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, complete-spaces

Continuous function on $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ that is not Lipschitz Continuous?

One example I could perhaps think of is $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x})$ where we define $f(0)=0$.

Then this function has the required domain and range. Now, I was wondering by defining $f(0)=0$, would we have continuity at $x=0$?

Also, I guess this is also Lipschitz continuous since $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}f(x)$ is unbounded?

How could I improve my argument? Thanks!

Comment: Have in mind that the example you gave is not a continuous function at $x=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thank you! I guess no matter what value I assign at $x=0$, $f(x)$ will never be continuous right? (since the graph oscillates even in a very small neighbourhood of $x=0$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not continuous at $0$ so does not work. It also cannot made continuous since the limit $x \to 0$ does not exist.

Instead, consider

$$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$$

This is continuous but not Lipschitz-continuous since the derivative is unbounded near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You function is not continuous at $0$. There is a way easier counter-example : the square-root function. Show it cannot be Lipschitz continuous on a neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f$ is not continuous at $0$: let $x_n:=(\pi/2+2n \pi)^{-1},$ then $x_n \to 0$ but $f(x_n)=1 \to 1 \ne 0=f(0).$

But $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$ will work.